# XML parsing error using LINQ

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have the following vb.net code:

```
Dim carsDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(sCarsXML)
Dim query = From ex In carsDoc.Descendants("car")
Select New With {
    .id = ex.Element("id").Value,
    .code = ex.Element("code").Value
}

For Each ex In query
    MsgBox("ID: " & ex.id.ToString & vbCrLf & "CODE: " & ex.code.ToString)
Next
```

I get the following error on line 9 (the MsgBox code):

> BC30451   'ex' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level.

I have added the needed references:

```
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Linq
```

I can't figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching on the internet, I've found the problem/solution:

"**Option Infer**" in the "**Compile**" section of the project settings was turned off. This is because I've converted the project from **.NET Framework 2.0** to **3.5**.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the items in `query` is not `XElement`, it's the anonymous type that is created by the `New With` statement.

Don't specify the type for the variable in the loop:

```
For Each ex In query
```

Comment: @milo2011: That's odd. With that change I don't get any error in the code.

Comment: Yes, I know, it's very strange. When I create a new project and add the code, it works without any error, but when I add the code as a part to my working project it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @milo2011: That suggests that the code that is actually causing the problem is somewhere else in that project.

Comment: @milo2011: You could try different things like seeing what Visual Studio tells you about variables when pointing at them, renaming variables, or put the code in a different class in the same project. As you get a completely unexpected result there is something that is not as it seems, so you would try to find anything that is unexpected.